# How can I modify this sliding div to actually work?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to incorporate the code that I found on this jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x2qk7/158/

Into my website but its not working.

Pasted from my actual page It looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.next').click(function(){             
        $('.slide').animate({left:-720})
    })

});​ </script>

<style>.form-slides {width:100000px;} .slide {width:300px;float:left;left:0;position:relative;}​</style>

<div class="form-slides">
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Lipsum blah blah blah</p>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Lipsum blah blah blah</p>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <p>Lipsum blah blah blah</p>
        <a href="#" class="next">Next</a> 
    </div> </div>
```

It seems to be exact, but its not working at all.  Am I missing something?

Comment: this isn't exactly the same: your slide width is different. and how is it 'not working'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is jQuery loaded?
2. I don't know what's your goal but I think changing `left` in animation may help to go to the 3rd and further slide

   ```
   $('a.next').click(function(){             
       $('.slide').animate({left: "-=785px"})
   })
   ```

   Try this.
3. To answer @Daniel Fein [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998577/how-can-i-modify-this-sliding-div-to-actually-work/13998615#comment19324156_13998615): yes there is a way and it's quite simple.
   Wrap it with a `<div>` and add `overflow:hidden` property to it. Just like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x2qk7/165/)

Comment: you're right I didn't load jquery, silly me.  But the next button only moves once, not every on every click of the next button.  Any idea?

Comment: basicaly when you click on next you set a predefined value of left (the first slide) but any further sliders are far from left ;) so you need to animate with `-=` operator to get values: `-785px`, `-1570px, ...`

Comment: Hey it worked! you rock!  Question now, because its div is set to 100000px, the window has a scroll bar that allows you to scroll all the way to the right.  Is there a way to hide the extra stuff that's not on the screen?

Comment: @DanielFein I've edited my answer just jump there and check it out ;)

Comment: Seriously, you're incredible! very smart! thank you soo much, happy holidays!!

Comment: Thanks happy holiday for you too ;)